# Saving a project as an .ipa

Tags: iphone, ipad

I wrote an app for the iPad, but I don't currently own an iPad.

I would like to save my project as an .ipa file (assuming it's .ipa for the iPad, like the iPhone) so I could send it to a friend with a Jailbroken iPad to test it on an actual device before I release it to the App Store.

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an adhoc provisioning profile, you distribute your app even to jail broken phones. Create a new target and sign it with your adhoc profile, then send the app and the profile to them.